# python regex splitting at wrong places

Tags: python, regex, string, python-2.7, split

I have the following regex and the input string.

```
pattern = re.compile(r'\s+(?=[^()|^{}|^<>]*(?:\(|\{|\<|$))')
string = "token1 token2 {a | op (b|c) | d}"
print pattern.split(string)
```

the result is : `["token1","token2","{a | op","(b|c) |d}"]`

I want the regex to give the following result : `["token1","token2","{a | op (b|c) | d}"]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string = "token1 token2 {a | op (b|c) | d}"
re.findall(r'\w+|\{.*}',string)
```

output:

```
['token1', 'token2', '{a | op (b|c) | d}']
```

Comment: suppose if i have the string as string = "token1 token2 {a | op (b|c) | d} ( e | f | g )" and i want result = ['token1', 'token2', '{a | op (b|c) | d}','( e | f | g )']

Comment: Add another OR condition that finds everything between the parentheses. Use the same pattern I did with finding everything between the braces.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply split by this

```
\s+(?![^{]*\})
```

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/WjQVqZ/1

Comment: suppose if i have the string as string = "token1 token2 {a | op (b|c) | d}  ( e | f | g )" and i want result = ['token1', 'token2', '{a | op (b|c) | d}','( e | f | g )']

Answer (score 0):

The raw pattern to use with the split method is `r'\s+(?=[^\}]*(?:\{|$))'`.

Every time whitespace is encountered, you want to look ahead for a closing curly brace, so you know if the white space is inside of braces - unless an opening curly brace or the end of the string is seen next.